# MVC5 OWIN ad and database

Tags: asp.net, owin, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm creating an MVC5 app.  It is an intranet app.  All users are already authenticated to the local Active Directory Domain.

We have an existing database that is currently used for a Windows app.

I want take the User's domain login name and use it to look up the roles and claims that are already configured in that database.

I will assume the the base project of ASP.NET / MVC5 / Authentication "Individual User Accounts" would be the starting point.

Please point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: Part of the issue is I don't want the user to have to log in again...they've already logged into Windows/AD.  They are already valid.  But I will re-read all responses with a clearer head in the morning.  Thanks Win & Clint B.

Comment: In your ApplicationUserManager.CheckPasswordAsync() override you can just return true.  Then in the Login controller's POST action, check to see if the current user exists in AD.  If so, call the SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync() method.  That will log them in automatically.  I know it's kind of convoluted but for some reason Microsoft didn't give us any support for Active Directory intranet sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .NET OWIN Identity classes require that you authenticate through the CheckPasswordAsync() method of the ApplicationUserManager class.  This can be done by overriding the CheckPasswordAsync() method of class ApplicationUserManager. In your override you will need to call the ValidateCredentials() method of class System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement to authenticate via Active Directory.  This will require the user to login to the application with their Windows username and password.  There are a few steps to get that to work though.

As you said, you start with a base project with "Individual User Accounts" authentication.

Step 1 - Update the ConfigureAuth() method in file App_Start\Startup.Auth.cs by adding the code below to the ConfigureAuth() method.

```
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;

//Add an Owin context for Active Directory principals
app.CreatePerOwinContext(() => new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain));
```

**The rest of the updates are done in file App_Start\IdentityConfig.cs**

Step 2 - Update the constructor for class ApplicationUserManager.

```
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;

//Add a PrincipalContext parameter to the constructor
public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store, PrincipalContext principal) : base(store)
{
    this.principal = principal;
}
```

Step 3 - In the Create() method update the call to the constructor for class ApplicationUserManager.

```
//Add the PrincipalContext parameter
var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<PortalIdentityDbContext>()), context.Get<PrincipalContext>());
```

Step 4 - Override the CheckPasswordAsync() method of class ApplicationUserManager.

```
//Override CheckPasswordAsync to login via Active Directory.
public override async Task<bool> CheckPasswordAsync(ApplicationUser user, string password)
{
    return await Task.FromResult(this.principal.ValidateCredentials(user.UserName, password, ContextOptions.Negotiate));
}
```

As for using your existing database, you will have to incorporate the OWIN Identity tables in it or vice-versa.  The Identity functionality requires those tables and you can't change that.  I would create a test project and get familiar with those tables.  Then figure out how you want to incorporate them into your existing database or vice-versa.  I heavily modify those tables for my custom functionality.  But the core tables and columns have to exist.

Comment: After doing a bit of research and digging I found this function...System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name will give me the current user's AD login name, strip off the domain am left with the exact name in the existing user table.  Now I just have to get my head around the OWIN Identity tables.

Comment: The OWIN Identity architecture is something you should get familiar with anyway.  Much like the Membership Providers of old.  Microsoft has stated that the OWIN Identity architecture is what they will be using for the foreseeable future.  So it will be a good skill to have.

Comment: One thing I forgot to mention in my post.  When creating a new user from the Registration page, the UserManager.CreateAsync() method requires a password.  You can just default it to something that passes the password validation in the Identity class.  It's not used when you're authenticating against AD.  But it still needs to be there.

Comment: I'll up vote you tomorrow.  I'm out of votes for the day.  Maybe you can return the favor. :-)

Comment: I've been watching more training videos and reading a bit more.  Looks like I want to use Claims for what I need and will need a custom store as I want to get all the data, including Claims from a WebAPI.  So more reading and learning to do.

Answer (score 2):

You do not want entire ASP.Net Identity. Instead, you can just use OWIN cookie authentication middleware.

### Validate Credential via Active Directory

```
public bool ValidateCredentials(string userName, string password)
{
   using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
   {
      return context.ValidateCredentials(userName, password);
   }
}
```

### Authorize via Old Database

Once authenticated, you want to retrieve authorized role from old Database, and create claims.

```
private readonly HttpContextBase _context;
private const string AuthenticationType = "ApplicationCookie";

public OwinAuthenticationService(HttpContextBase context)
{
    _context = context;
}

public void SignIn(User user)
{
    IList<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>
    {
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Sid, user.Id.ToString()),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName, user.FirstName),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Surname, user.LastName),
    };

    // Get authorized roles from old database
    foreach (Role role in user.Roles)
    {
        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role.Name));
    }

    ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, AuthenticationType);

    IOwinContext context = _context.Request.GetOwinContext();
    IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager = context.Authentication;

    authenticationManager.SignIn(identity);
}

public void SignOut()
{
    IOwinContext context = _context.Request.GetOwinContext();
    IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager = context.Authentication;

    authenticationManager.SignOut(AuthenticationType);
}
```

### Startup.cs

You also need to configure Startup for all those to happen.

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(YourApplication.Startup))]
namespace YourApplication
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = "ApplicationCookie",
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I hope you get the starting point.

Comment: Thanks for this...I will be using items from both answers to learn what's going on.